# How to check if a class has a mixin applied in TypeScript? (inferring its type)

Tags: typescript, mixins

I am trying to determine if a TypeScript class has a specific mixin applied to it in a way that narrows its type (for autocompletion/intellisense), but I am encountering some difficulties. I have tried two different approaches, but neither has been successful.

Option 1 ([link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQqQFMAu0BCAsgJYAeRAdtALzQAUEArgA6YBOokEAXNGOQJ4BKagD5oHKPmiYS2TOQAmMRi3bhJCVNGgAjAAqsA9kx4RsrCgHNq0AET6jTWwG4tugjgAWhhbWGbtbWBDcghDLAA6EENLWlsAWy8faAAzI3j8W0FXbTRkV1Rg0NwAYRtCUgpaWEFCkLNxG3JMAHdoEtcisMjo2OBoCjM%20YExDFPxhAHpJ9r5yQ1wUigVocjBE6AByPE3UIA)): Adding a name to the class inside the mixin. This approach did not work as the class is not defined inside the mixin but rather when the mixin is called. As a result, `instanceof` does not recognize it. Here is the code:

```
class A { }

let BMixin = (superclass: any) => class B extends superclass {
  bProp: string = "bProp";
  bMethod() {
    console.log("method from B");
  }
};

const C = BMixin(A)
const c = new C;
console.log(c instanceof B) // Cannot find name 'B'
```

Option 2 ([link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQrSRgIUa60ARgAoBOA9gA4Bc0EALqQJYB2A5tALzQBEJFlHgG58RALIBTegAtyAEwAUASjwECwciwjkQEgHQhybBTwC2E2fTnQAZhVPRsPJSIJo0qGwFcWwek01oOQkbVgkxJgAPVmgFUyjWAGFwKFowFgBPFQRRUikvUhZYsFI2AAY0zJVOAD5oTChoCUj6CRY5GBLy1TUAel7oAAkJPOgASTpZLxBrOXI6cnNoUzA2JmBoenmNSgzN6QllqVkO6HTrSgER-wkIUXd0DS16aAARLiCQsIjolgVsJQKWBKDCaBhBD4sCQAdzeIie2l0BiMCmsrAY6WAEnINkcKn6tjAIAgElQQA)): Creating a utility that receives a class and returns a mixin. The problem with this approach is that (a) I would have to find a way to copy all the methods and properties and (b) `instanceof` keeps returning false. Here is the code:

```
class A { }

class B {
  bProp: string = "bProp";
  bMethod() {
    console.log("method from B");
  }
}

function defineMixin (mixinClass: any) {
  return (arg0: any) => class extends arg0 {
    // Here I should do some magic to copy the methods and properties
  }
}

const D = defineMixin(B)(A)
const d = new D;
console.log(d instanceof B) // false
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63123767/mixin-pattern-with-typescript) in which [@elias-schablowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11986202/elias-schablowski) gets the type of the resulting class to have the methods and properties of the mixins. However, the Typescript compiler doesn't really get to know the prototype chain, and therefore you can't narrow the types of an arbitrary class.

In other words, I want to be able to do:

```
if (something instanceof someMixin) { // ¿Or ~ hasSomeMixin(something)?
    // here I want "something" to have the autocomplete
    // with all the properties and methods of "someMixin".
}
```

And also this:

```
const Something = CMixin(BMixin(A))
const something = new Something;
// here I want "something" to have the autocomplete
// with all the properties and methods of "A", "B" and "C".
```

I also found that the `ts-mixer` library offers an alternative function to `instanceof` called [hasMixin](https://github.com/tannerntannern/ts-mixer#hasmixin) that serves this purpose.
The problem is that this library (~2kb GZipped) modifies the base class prototype in a very complex way, and only works under certain restrictions. E.g., I understand that `this` and `super` cannot be used .

I would like a simpler solution that works [with all the benefits](https://github.com/justinfagnani/mixwith.js#advantages-of-subclass-factories-over-typical-javascript-mixins) of chaining prototypes without modifying them in some strange way.

How can I do this? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you need to know it's type? You should be able to understand this at compile time. Not knowing that seems a code smell

Comment: I think you are not understanding. Exactly what I'm trying to do is make Typescript understand types at compile time.

Comment: Because `console.log(c instanceof c.constructor)` is true, the constructor name of the dynamic sub-typing approach (which is **not a mixin** pattern) of `B` ... `class B extends superclass { }` ... can be revealed via `c.constructor.name` which for the OP's first code example equals `"B"`.

Comment: _"I would like a simpler solution that works with all the benefits of chaining prototypes without modifying them in some strange way."_ ... this solution exists and is called inheritance. But the dynamic subtyping approach (a factory function which creates a subclass on the fly) which TypeScript as much successfully as mistakenly has coined "mixin" prevents any other reference to a subclassed constructor than the one via `instance.constructor`.

Comment: Exact. If I am understanding you correctly, you are reinforcing some of my ideas. The factory function doesn't seem workable. Any ideas using the first approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve it.

#### 1. Context

Suppose a `BMixin` that can only receive subclasses of `class A`.

```
class A { }


type Ctor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type SubA = Ctor<A>

function BMixin<TBase extends SubA>(Base: TBase) {
  return class B extends Base {
    bProp: string = "bProp";
    bMethod() {
      console.log("method from B");
    }
  };
}
```

#### 2. SOLUTION: generic type guard

We can define a `guard type` as follows:

```
export type Block<T extends SubA = SubA> =
  InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof BMixin<T>>>;

function hasBMixin<T extends SubA>(
  input: any,
  klass?: ReturnType<typeof BMixin<T>>
): input is Block<T> {
  // any runtime check that lets you know that input has the mixin
  if (!klass) return "bProp" in input;
  return input instanceof klass;
}
```

#### 3. USAGE: simple case

And it is used as follows:

```
const a = "a" as unknown;
if (hasBMixin(a)) {
  a.bMethod()
}
```

#### 4. USAGE: advanced case

You can even narrow the type to a specific subclass of A

```
class subA1 extends A {
  subA1Method() {
    console.log("method from subA1")
  };
}
const C = BMixin(subA1)

if (hasBMixin(a, C)) {
  a.bMethod()
  a.subA1Method();
}
```

[Link to the full example in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=2&pln=40&pc=1#code/PTAEEYDpQYQeQHIBUCiANJAuUBDUAhAWQEsAPYgO1ABcALHa0AYxyoHsKAbAT1ACcApkwHEAbgNABnAK4AjJpxyTJAyaDYAzZouWgAgpABQhhUrV7QAb1ABfY9W4AHCTGps%20AHiQA%20UAF5QCgEAd1AACkhInD4Ac0lsVm4AbQBdAEp-XyQAbkMHZ1AAZTkLANd3Dz1vYw1pCiZqYg4CEnIKL3wlCQFSagEKABM1YtkqsM6VbCQJgQzLQ1B%20AWppPipTXXxQHr7BtRmrBcXQWQAFPjZHbElqPkoY-1AAIjOLxyfc45PCZdo2AbCcyOXyYHEkbE4AkgnDYMTCTwAtr9-qANBcEQQnmlPsc7IsbLk7IYQKAAEzQQpwAAyAFUkABJRDYGL9AR3Jg0JwSGLSaIDYw9RzuRj5CT4GFMADWXm2vX6QyKJUeIyq-iO9IoN1YwiQXI8ACVlqsKLrnB5RZoWmRKF5vHbcoZavVGs16JIiNb2khZbsFSrvGEjpRHNJqAkKNwADRHSU6SQAfmwhpWa1NAnNXMtHratuqaWwwdDoGI%20wl0p8h0WJMS-DqjSRzFoQklNHojEh1DU3DY0lAkoobFCdAYxYoIcYbtbEgRnqDWjCAEJY2YMoIU1QXudLk9R6Pxzi18a90XKFr6gJLcvlITjCSAMzQGmFPQAcRQ12ICMckOYXWMoM1Rg8ACJ4cB3JRQDqftBwoXJiHnN1s0oMIcDSIFFhwSBZB%20Oh-kBQwiRJAAWR9nzfBIBlEbUBAGX8VH-OMpBKcAfXlcxKyY0ZwBwv4AXQ44APBSFoVheEkVw2i0TYDEZC4rEjgJAiTDBRgYEeJCKDCWS9HANJjHg8JENaZCcEjWA0I4zDsORPijkw7TuJswEbyAA)

Credits to [this subcomment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777844/how-to-sanely-handle-conditional-ts-class-mixins#comment131989399_74777844) by @GeoffHarper which inspired this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution, I've found one. Essentially, try creating a dummy class variable for the mixin and using a function with a type predicate to check to tell the compiler it's an instance of the mixin.

```js
class A { }

let BMixin = (superclass: any) => class B extends superclass {
  bProp: string = "bProp";
  bMethod() {
    console.log("method from B");
  }
};

// Create a dummy B class and a function with a type predicate to do the actual checking
const B = Bmixin(A);
function isInstanceB(obj: any) : obj is InstanceType<typeof B> {
  return 'bMethod' in obj;
}

class C extends BMixin(A) {}
const instance_C = new C();

function printIfB(thing: A) {
  if (isInstanceB(thing)) {
    thing.bMethod() // prints "method from B"
  }
}

printIfB(instance_C);
```

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1pgIwC5oDsCuAtgEYCmATgNwpoBM2+x5V1wA9jhAC5l7CetkAFBnqFSZADS1RjMgEpE1VJwAWASwgA6DNAC8adFVTL1WsDT20j0AL5I7STgE8ADiWgBhdlx58BlnBIAd0FNMLAyAHMIbDAcJwBtAF0FXQA+RBFcMXIpcxlxGyoAMzwcPjV2aAI1AA81HAAeABVoElrOEhwAExgvDm5efjI0wSJIEmxmhWRUMhJOPDIcaFBIGHbOnphxiHdZ4zBu7sEZpWN5xeXoVQ1tdGgAahvTbRprVDtP+yQkNgHoAAhXbufQ1eo4QSwOQlMoVKoaACSAziwBIwImglYRAAVrF4gpsNicdANNBkVxUSRmq4SI1nG5WMUgSCMgdLksVgByI7dLmklbEqgONZQIFtDpdXrVOoNKEzEXeTgCynlEgAfUBAWCQME6CkNBhv1K5U4lRW3VYsGOgluOEi2GhilQamZgiRKLVGL2tvU9rkZ2Mq28rBAJE0IFYkV9DUi2htAesdgclutJwaqrRmphQA) (though the A and B classes are different, it does the same thing)

It's not the cleanest, but also IMO not the worst, either. This method also handles the situation in which you want to compose multiple mixins and check to see if a subclass implements any of them.

Comment: The problem with this is that `isInstanceB` cannot be used to check that anything has the BMixin. I just posted an answer that solves this.